# using fetch to upload an image, I get a 200 status, but the image does not upload

Tags: javascript, apache, react-native, fetch

In my React Native app, I want to use fetch to upload an image file to my server.  I'm getting a 200 response, but the image does not upload.  My fetch looks like...

```
let url = Config.base_url + '/photos'
let filename = this.state.image.substr(this.state.image.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
// filename: something.jpg

 let data = new FormData()
 data.append('photo', {
   uri: this.state.image,
   type: 'image/jpeg',
   name: filename
 })

 fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
```

In the Apache error log there is no error.

The entry in my access log looks like...

```
123.45.67.89 - - [26/Jul/2018:18:47:30 +0000] "GET /photos/ HTTP/1.1" 200 649 "-" "Ally/1 CFNetwork/901.1 Darwin/17.7.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to tell without seeing your server code, but there are a few things you should check.

1. Your access log says "GET" although your code says it's using "POST". Are you sure that's the correct log entry?
2. In your server, in the function that receives the photo, can you log the incoming request? Try logging the body and seeing if it's what you expect to see.
3. Can you manually send a request from another service such as cURL or an app like [this](https://github.com/mmattozzi/cocoa-rest-client)? If that works, then the problem is in how you are sending the request. If that doesn't work, it could be that there is an issue in your server.

Comment: Thanks Neel.  I may have the wrong expectation of fetch in this case.  I was thinking I could move the file directly into the target directory with fetch.  But it sounds like I need a script on the server to handle the request.  I may have to do a bit more searching for code samples.  I had the same thought re: GET vs POST in the access log -- yeah, it's the right entry.  Could be a byproduct of my attempt to move the file directly to the server with fetch (as if I were using scp).

Comment: Yea, typically you will need some code to receive the message, parse the data, and then save the file. Unless you are using a pre-built API or library, which already handles this stuff for you.